# ¿Como hacer que el usuario ingrese número impar? 1, 3, 5, 7, etc

Tags: python, lista, game

He intentado crear el programa para jugar "Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard & Spock", como lo había hecho para crear el juego simple de "Rock, paper, Scissors", sin embargo no ´puedo con las indicaciones que me pidieron:

Además, también deberá mejorar la forma en que el juego interactúa con el jugador: el número de rondas a jugar, que debe ser un número impar, se solicitará al usuario hasta que se ingrese un número válido. Defina una nueva función para hacer esa solicitud.

¿Podrían auxiliarme por favor? este es el código que utilicé:

```
import random

gestures = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'lizard', 'spock']

n_rounds = 0
cpu_score = 0
player_score = 0

import random

gestures = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'lizard', 'spock']

n_rounds = 0
cpu_score = 0
player_score = 0

def rounds_to_win(gestures):
    rounds_to_win = print("How many rounds you want to play? Introduce an odd number")
    while rounds_to_win %2 == 0:
        if rounds_to_win % 2 > 0:
            print("This isn't a valid option. Introduce an odd numbe")
        elif rounds_to_win %2 < 0:
            print("You chose", rounds_to_win)

def cpu_choice (gestures):
    return random.choice(gestures)

def player_choice(gestures):
    player_choice = input("Stone, paper, scissors, lizard or spock?. Please, type your choice.")
    
    while player_choice not in gestures:
        player_choice = input("That's not an option. Stone, paper, scissors, lizard or spock?")
        
        if player_choice == "stone":
            print("You choose stone")
        elif player_choice == "paper":
            print("You choose paper")
        elif player_choice == "scissors":
            print("You choose scissor")
        elif player_choice == "lizard":
            print("You choose lizard")
        elif player_choice == "spock":
            print("You choose Spock")
    
    return str(player_choice)

def choice(gestures):
    print("You chose:", player_choice)
    print("CPU chose:", cpu_choice)
    if player_choice == "stone" and cpu_choice == "stone":
        print("Stone vs stone. It's a tie")
        cpu_score += 0
        player_score += 0
        n_rounds += 1
    elif player_choice == "paper" and cpu_choice == "paper":
        print("Paper vs paper. It's a tie")
        cpu_choice += 0
        player_score += 0
        n_rounds += 1
    elif player_choice == "scissors" and cpu_choice == "scissors":
        print("Scissors vs scissors. It's a tie")
        cpu_score += 0
        player_score += 0
        n_rounds += 1
        
    elif player_choice == "stone" and cpu_choice == "paper":
        print("Stone vs paper. You loose")
        cpu_score += 0
        player_score += 2
        n_rounds += 1
    elif player_choice == "stone" and cpu_choice == "scissors":
        print("Stone vs scissors. You win")
        cpu_choice += 1
        player_score += 0
        n_rounds += 1
        
    elif player_choice == "paper" and cpu_choice == "stone":
        print("Paper vs stone. You win")
        cpu_score += 0
        player_score += 2
        n_rounds += 1
    elif player_choice == "paper" and cpu_choice == "scissors":
        print("Paper vs Scissors. You loose")
        cpu_choice += 1
        player_score += 0
        n_rounds += 1
    
    elif player_choice == "scissors" and cpu_choice == "paper":
        print("Scissors vs paper. You win")
        cpu_score += 0
        player_score += 2
        n_rounds += 1
    elif player_choice == "scissors" and cpu_choice == "stone":
        print("Scissors vs stone. You loose")
        cpu_choice += 1
        player_score += 0
        n_rounds += 1
        
def winner():
    print((player_score) - (cpu_score))
    
while n_rounds < 5:
    rounds_to_win(gestures)
    player_choice(gestures)
    cpu_choices = cpu_choice(gestures)
    winner()
    if player_score > cpu_score:
        print("You won")
    else:
        print("CPU won")
```

Comment: en lugar de preguntar por el juego como conjunto, que es algo muy genérico, sería mejor enfocar la pregunta en el ámbito de la programación: cómo selecciono X? cómo itero Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas dos validaciones, **una** para corroborar que lo ingresado sea efectivamente un numero, y **otra** para asegurarte de que ese número es impar, podes probar lo siguiente:

```
try:
    rondas = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de rondas que desee jugar."))
    if (rondas % 2) == 0:
        raise Exception
    #Si llega aca es porque pasó las dos validaciones mencionadas
except:
    print("La opcion ingresada es inválida, debe ser un número impar.")
```

Como sabemos que al intentar converir un string con letras a entero en python con la funcion **`int()`** nos dispara un error, lo aprovechamos para realizar la primera validación.
En el segundo caso verificamos si el número es divisible por dos, para asegurarnos de que sea impar. Si es par forzamos el error para informarle al usuario que su opcion es incorrecta.